# Git merge reverted, not merge all files in future merge

Tags: git, git-extensions

I created a branch and made some changes in there. I merged the master into my branch, but this was to early so I reverted this merge-commit. After that I made some new changes an commited multiple times.

```
...--o--o--*  -- o--o--o-----o   <-- master
            \     \           \
             o--o--o--x--o--o--o--o  <-- mybranch
                      |           |
             reverted merge       not merge all files
```

So if I want to merge now, it ignores files which was removed with the revert.

How can I merge all files, without ignoring some files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your branch is still only local, you could do an interactive rebase and skip the bad merge and revert then try to merge again.

You need to get your branch back into a state where the files in the first merge are untouched by your branch. That means actually undoing that merge as if it didn't happen, not just doing a revert commit.

Comment: So I have to go back to the merge commit or earlier an readd my commits excepts of the revert commit?

Comment: Yes, well, before the merge commit. That way your branch continues on as if the merge wasn't there. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgsk6.png